# Web database for linking pages with comments

Tags: web-apps, open-source, database, hyperlink

I want to create a database linking different web pages together. Each such link should be able to carry one or several comments to.

I want to be able to search it by URLs, titles and comments.

There should be an API so I could use this from different software (like Wordpress etc).

The software I am looking for to do this should be open source and run on a web server (maybe my own server). I expect it to use MySQL and a common programming language.

Is there any such software available?

Comment: How do you want it to look different web pages together? Like are you of a x is related to a, b and c type thing or ??

Comment: @NickWilde That is a second step. The database will be a bidirectional graph. I do not know the current state of software for displaying such graphs, but I am interested. Html5 should be a big help there.

Comment: For the graphs there is a terrific answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript - probably one of the best sources on this site. (Since it was closed there it should be moved here in some way, perhaps.)

Comment: So in practice a bookmarking web application?

Comment: Bookmarking+discussion+graphs, @Nemo . At the moment I do not do much about it, but I think it will be using Lucene instead (problably http://opensearchserver.com/).

Comment: http://archive.is/ does store the link graph in some way, no comments or tags though. I don't know if their code is available somewhere.